# Can't run JACK on Mac OS HS 10.13.2

Tags: python, macos, jack

I've installed JACK-Client with pip, but when importing jack I get this error

```
>>> import jack
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jack.py", line 44, in <module>
    raise OSError('JACK library not found')
OSError: JACK library not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to first install the Jack libriary for OS X, which is available on the [Jackaudio download page](http://jackaudio.org/downloads/).